# how to get payment response if my server stop working when callback url call by payment getway

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am working on stripe payment getaway one question is arising in my mind.this question in few steps i have defined below.

1. customer generate a payment request on my server
2. after input successful details customer request submitted on stripe.
3. stripe payment getaway done their process and  they send me  response either success or failure.
4. now what happen when stripe send me success or failure that time my server stopped working. then obviously i am not able to save stripe response in my tables. even i don't have record what my customer paid to my website.

so how would we know the stripe response even after my server stopped working on stripe callback.

i am using PHP for this.

Comment: Which integration method are you using? Stripe Checkout? https://stripe.com/docs/checkout

Comment: yes stripe checkout or i am also using dodirect payment

Answer (score 0):

I note that you originally tagged this question with PayPal. You should understand that Stripe works differently how a conventional PayPal checkout flow would work.

With PayPal the shopper arrives at the end of your checkout flow, they click a link to get transferred to PayPal, they login/register, confirm their card details and then PayPal sends a callback to your server. This is where your point about your server being down is relevant.

With Stripe Checkout the flow is different. You add the Stripe javascript code to the final page of your checkout, this triggers a panel (like a modal window) where the shopper enters their card details. Upon submission Stripe generates a token for the card and then adds this as a hidden fields to the form on your site.

You set the form action to point to some code on your server. Upon submission your PHP script then takes the token and processes a payment.

At no point is there a callback between Stripe and your site. Instead you take the payment in a single call from your server. Once you get a response from this API call then you can log the order in your database, send confirmation emails, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you but my query isn't full fill yet. i am just simply asking that  how would we know the stripe response even after my server stopped working on (stripe,paypal,or any other payment getway) callback

Comment: Do you understand my point that the PayPal and Stripe flows are different? For Stripe you send the API request to take a payment and then you get back the response. It seems like you're asking what happens if you send an API request but then your server goes down within the fraction of a second until the API responds?